# DRUPAL db_or adding AND between multiple variables

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

I have inherited an application that is using the drupal filtering system to find results. The user can select to search the 'campus_location' column but when they enter multiple variables, it adds an AND between the condition.

Here is the printed version of the query generated by drupal:

```
SELECT * FROM champs c INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = c.uid LEFT OUTER JOIN champs_rsvp r 
ON r.uid = c.uid LEFT OUTER JOIN champs_checklists cl 
ON cl.id = c.checklist_id LEFT OUTER JOIN node en 
ON en.uid = u.uid AND en.type = 'getting_started_event' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN node sn ON sn.uid = u.uid 
AND sn.type = 'success_story' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN champs_action_steps cas 
ON cas.uid = u.uid 
WHERE ( (c.campus_location LIKE 'Flint' ESCAPE '\\') )
**AND**( (c.campus_location LIKE 'Ann Arbor' ESCAPE '\\') )
```

I need the last AND to be an OR so it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM champs c INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = c.uid LEFT OUTER JOIN champs_rsvp r 
ON r.uid = c.uid LEFT OUTER JOIN champs_checklists cl 
ON cl.id = c.checklist_id LEFT OUTER JOIN node en 
ON en.uid = u.uid AND en.type = 'getting_started_event' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN node sn ON sn.uid = u.uid 
AND sn.type = 'success_story' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN champs_action_steps cas 
ON cas.uid = u.uid 
WHERE ( (c.campus_location LIKE 'Flint' ESCAPE '\\') )
OR( (c.campus_location LIKE 'Ann Arbor' ESCAPE '\\') )
```

Which produces the correct results.

Here is the code that I inherited where it looks over the words in the search box. I just can't seem to figure out where it is adding the variables where it is putting the AND.

```
$words = explode(",", $_SESSION['form_state']['values']['filter']);

    foreach($words as $word)
    {

        $or = db_or();
        foreach($cols as $col)
        {
            $table = 'c';
            if(in_array($col, array('completed_date', 'score')))
                $table = 'cl';
            elseif(in_array($col, array('name', 'mail')))
                $table = 'u';
            elseif($col == 'date')
                $table = 'r';
            elseif(in_array($col, array('announce', 'num_success_stories', 'num_action_steps')))    //can't put these in WHERE clause. Need to go in HAVING. 
                continue;
            echo $word;
            $or = $or->condition($table . '.' . $col, champs_make_like_sql($word), 'LIKE');

        }
        $result = $query->condition($or);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, why does it see that db_or() is just added AND statements. There is not 1 OR statement in the whole generated query.

Comment: please update with the entire value of $query as how the query is instantiated will be the biggest clue.